# How to convert a multi-dimensional array containing multiple arrays of tuples to lists in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I am using the function below to convert a multidimensional array of several arrays which have tuples inside them. The result should be similar to the desired_result.

```
sample_md_array = [[(99, 'string_1'), (45, 'string_2')], [(15, 'string_3'), (48, 'string_4')]]

def convert(md_array):
    new_array = []
    for array in md_array:
        for tup in array:
            new_array.append(list(tup))

    return new_array

result_using_convert_function = [[99, 'string_1'], [45, 'string_2'], [15, 'string_3'], [48, 'string_4']]

desired_result = [[[99, 'string_1'], [45, 'string_2']], [[15, 'string_3'], [48, 'string_4']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could a list comprehension to convert the tuples to lists:

```
>>> sample_tuple = [[(99, 'string_1'), (45, 'string_2')], [(15, 'string_3'), (48, 'string_4')]]
>>> [[list(y) for y in x] for x in sample_tuple]
[[[99, 'string_1'], [45, 'string_2']], [[15, 'string_3'], [48, 'string_4']]]
```